# How to convert CloudFileStream to FileStream?

Tags: c#, azure, filestream

I have an application which uses `IO.FileStream` to read files. We are moving storage to Azure File storage. How do I convert `CloudFileStream` to `IO.FileStream` in c#?

Comment: You likely cannot. The best you can probably do is change your code to work on the common base type `Stream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these classes are siblings (both derive from `Stream`) and do not have parent/child relationship there is no direct way to convert one to another. You need to use local file to use `FileStream` and than copy to Azure's [CloudFileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfilestream.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Notes

- it is generally better to use `Stream` as parameter to most methods as you'll be able to handle more types (including these two).
- If you plan to keep `FileStream` and copy content of `CloudFileStream` to/from lcal file before calling your methods - create temporary files using [Path.GetTemplFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) ans name and make sure to clean them up after operation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 possible answers depending on what you want to do,

if you want to write a class that can work with both types of stream then the simplest way is to base that class around the abstract [stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is common to all streams

if you want to copy data from one stream to another then you can use the [CopyTo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) however requires .Net4 or higher

from MSDN

```
// Create the streams.
MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream();

using (FileStream source = File.Open(@"c:\temp\data.dat",
    FileMode.Open))
{

    Console.WriteLine("Source length: {0}", source.Length.ToString());

    // Copy source to destination.
    source.CopyTo(destination);
}

Console.WriteLine("Destination length: {0}", destination.Length.ToString());
```